# Sequelize - Combination Operators

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize operators confuse me and I'm wondering if anyone has any advice on how to approach building something that essentially takes a search term and applies it to multiple potential fields. I build the query object because I want to conditionally search via email, firstname, lastname only if the searchTerm is present.

example: select * from book where title LIKE 'hello' OR author LIKE 'hello' OR coauthor LIKE 'hello'

```
     // add searchTerm to query, the search term could be email, firstname, or lastname
     if (request.query.searchTerm) {
        let searchTerm = request.query.searchTerm;
        let orObject = { email: { $like: searchTerm}, firstname: { $like: searchTerm}, lastname: { $like: searchTerm}}
        
       query['$or'] = orObject;


    }
    // add organizationId to all queries
    query['organizationId'] = request.body.user.organizationId;

    await User.findAll({
        where: query,

    }).then(async userData => {
       console.log(userData);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
...
```

Error I currently get:
Error: Invalid value { email: { '$like': 'hello' } }

after JSON.stringify(query):
query: `{"email":"hello","$or":{"email":{"$like":"hello"},"firstname":{"$like":"hello"},"lastname":{"$like":"hello"}},,"organizationId":1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend to use `Op` from `sequelize` package to indicate operators instead of using `$or` or other similar operators.
Second, in order to use `OR` properly you need to list all conditions in an array like this:

```js
let orObject = [
  { email: { $like: searchTerm} },
  { firstname: { $like: searchTerm} },
  { lastname: { $like: searchTerm} }
]
        
query[Or.or] = orObject;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I adjusted things a bit but I think it essentially is doing what my original code was and the result is the same: Error: Invalid value { '$like': 'hello' }

Comment: Actually I got things going by following through with ALL of your advice :) I updated $like to [Op.like] as well. Thanks!